# Push css/js files from one component to another

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-components

I created 2 components: `layouts/app.blade.php` and `navigation.blade.php`

The `layouts/app.blade.php` looks like this:

```
<body>
    @stack('styles')
    <x-navigation/>
</body>
```

The `navigation.app.blade` looks like this:

```
<nav>
    @push('styles')
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="navigation.css"/>
    @endpush
</nav>
```

The problem is that my `@push()` method is not working. From what I understand the component that is pushing should also extend the layout, but this is not possible because the navigation should not inherit all the layout's content.
There's any possibility for me to send the css/js files from a component to another component without extending it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new file `layouts/default.blade.php`

```
<body>
    @stack('styles')
    {{ $slot }}
</body>
```

Change `layouts/app.blade.php` to

```
<x-layouts.default>
    <x-navigation/>
    {{ $slot }}
</x-layouts.default>
```